# How can I perform a scatter/gather operation on types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, existential-type

I have tree that hold contains nodes of different types. These are tagged using a datatype:

```
data Wrapping = A Int
              | B String
```

I want to write two functions:

```
scatter :: Wrapping -> a
gather :: a -> Output
```

The idea is that I can use (scatter.gather) :: Wrapping -> Output. There will of course be several different variations on both the scatter and the gather function (with each scatter variant having a unique Wrappingn datatype, but the set of intermediate types will always be the same) and I want to be able to cleanly compose them.

The issue that I have is that the type parameter a is not really free, it is a small explicit set of types (here it is {Int,String}). If I try to encode what I have so far into Haskell typeclasses then I get to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
data Wrapping = A Int | B String

class Fanin a where
        gather :: a -> String
instance Fanin Int where
        gather x = show x
instance Fanin String where
        gather x = x

class Fanout a where
        scatter :: Fanout a => Wrapping -> a
instance Fanout Int where
        scatter (A n) = n
instance Fanout String where
        scatter (B x) = x

combined = gather.scatter
```

The two classes typecheck fine but obviously the final line throws errors because ghc knows that the type parameters do match on every case, only on the two that I have defined. I've tried various combinations of extending one class from the other:

```
class Fanin a => Fanout a where ...
class Fanout a => Fanin a where ...
```

Finally I've looked at GADTs and existential types to solve this but I am stumbling around in the dark. I can't find a way to express a legal qualified type signature to GHC, where I've tried combinations of:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
class (forall a. Fanout a) => Fanin a where
class (forall a. Fanin a) => Fanout a where
```

Question: how do I express to GHC that I want to restrict `a` to only the two types in the set?

I get the feeling that the solution lies in one of the techniques that I've looked at but I'm too lost to see what it is...

Comment: Maybe you could get better answers if you explained _why_ you want these scatter/gather functions?

Comment: It's to represent different languages within an interpreter, preserving the constraints from each kind of "source" in the typed languages. I think Sam has actually given me the answer that I'm looking for, I just need to think about it for a bit before accepting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need something like the following:

```
module Main ( main ) where

-- Different kinds of wrapper data types
data WrapperA = A Int | B String
data WrapperB = C Int | D Float

-- A single intermediate data type (with phantom type)
data Intermediate a = E Int | F String

-- Generic scatter and gather functions
class Wrapped a where
  scatter :: Wrapped a => a -> Intermediate a
  gather :: Wrapped a => Intermediate a -> String

-- Specific scatter and gather implementations
instance Wrapped WrapperA where
  scatter (A i) = E i
  scatter (B s) = F s
  gather (E i) = show i
  gather (F s) = s

instance Wrapped WrapperB where
  scatter (C i) = E i
  scatter (D f) = F $ show f
  gather (E i) = show i
  gather (F s) = s ++ " was a float"

-- Beautiful composability
combined :: Wrapped a => a -> String
combined = gather . scatter

wrapperAexample1 = A 10
wrapperAexample2 = B "testing"
wrapperBexample1 = C 11
wrapperBexample2 = D 12.4

main :: IO ()
main = do print $ combined wrapperAexample1
          print $ combined wrapperAexample2
          print $ combined wrapperBexample1
          print $ combined wrapperBexample2
```

The main issue seems to be that you have an intermediate type which can have different kinds of content, but this is constant for different wrappers. Still, depending on the kind of wrapper, you want the `gather` function to behave differently.

To do this, I would define the `Intermediate` type to specify the kinds of values that can be held in the intermediate stage, and give it a phantom type parameter (to remember what kind of wrapper it originated from). You can then define a class to hold the `scatter` and `gather` functions, and define these differently for different kinds of wrappers.

The code above compiles without errors for me, and gives the following output:

```
"10"
"testing"
"11"
"12.4 was a float"
```

As you can see, the `WrapperB`/`D Float` input is treated differently than the `WrapperA`/`B String` (it is tagged as a float value, even after it has been converted to a String). This is because in the `Intermediate` representation it is remembered that the origin is a `WrapperB`: the one is of type `Intermediate WrapperA`, the other of `Intermediate WrapperB`.

If, on the other hand, you don't actually want the gather function to behave differently for different wrappers, you can simply take that out of the class and take out the phantom type. The easiest way to let ghc know that the type in the intermediate stage can be `Int` or `String` seems to me to still define something like the `Intermediate` type, rather than use just `a`.

Comment: I think this works. I may not need the phantom type, but the raw idea I can take is to construct a larger wrapper for the intermediate so that each of the different forms of intermediate can project onto it without loss.

Comment: Yup, this can be extended onto the full problem. Cheers, I hadn't thought of over-approximating the language in the middle that the gathers are defined. Very nice.

Answer (score 1):

> The idea is that I can use (scatter.gather) :: Wrapping -> Output.
>   There will of course be several different variations on both the
>   scatter and the gather function (with each scatter variant having a
>   unique Wrappingn datatype, but the set of intermediate types will
>   always be the same) and I want to be able to cleanly compose them.

If I understand correctly, you'd like to have different `Wrapping` types but the intermediate `a` type is constantly `Either Int String`. We can just reflect this information in our classes:

```
data Wrapping = A Int
              | B String

class Fanout wrap where
    scatter :: wrap -> Either Int String

instance Fanout Wrapping where
    scatter (A n) = Left n
    scatter (B str) = Right str

class Fanin output where
    gather :: Either Int String -> output

instance Fanin String where
    gather = either show id

combined :: Wrapping -> String
combined = gather . scatter
```

Also, this use case doesn't seem especially amenable to type classes, from what I can glean from the question. In particular, we can get rid of `Fanin`, and then `combined = either show id . scatter` looks better to my eyes than the previous definition.

The type class solution makes sense here only if just a single `Either Int String -> a` or `a -> Either Int String` function makes sense for each `a`, and you'd like to enforce this.